# Broken laptop monitor and external monitor have the same resolution and can't get the external to change

Tags: resolution

I stupidly slammed the top down on my Dell laptop and broke the monitor.  I can still see the icons but am unable to adjust the resolution to make the desktop usable.  I attached my external monitor but the same display shows up on that one.  I can't adjust the resolution on the external either.  I'm hoping that I just broke the monitor and not the computer.  Is there anyway to check this?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using 12.04, first is try to set the resolution of your monitor on the proper tool inside of the "system configuration" with the purpose of to make sure that the resolution can be changed without complications.

[image]

[image]

If so, then your laptop graphics (GPU) card is in good condition and you will only need to replace the crystal liquid display (LCD) and you also have the option of working with your external monitor only.

This and other characteristics can be configured in the same tool.

It would be very useful if you indicate us the make and model of your laptop with the purpose of knowing what graphics card it has and thus be able to give you an answer more personalized.

Best regards.

*P.S. My system is in Spanish, the illustrations are in this language.*

Answer (score 0):

sounds like when you slammed the lid you might have loosen up something on the motherboard If you still have video its not broken.

also make sure you system is up to date terminal type sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade

and post you fglrxinfo for terminal.